# Combine all arrays in object into one array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google chrome and I'd like to combine all arrays in a certain object into one array instead of them being split. So right now, my console o

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(all) {
// this returns everything in chrome's storage. 
}
```

It looks something like this in my console:

[image]

However, I'd like it to actually have all the arraries combined into one, as such:

**Object**

*feed_0: Array[364]*

I've tried this:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(all) {
  var test = {}; test = all;
  delete test['currently.settings'];

console.log(test);

var alpha = [];

var result = 0;
  for(var prop in test) {
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       var second = alpha.concat(prop);

      console.log(second);
    // or Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)
      result++;
    }
  }

   });
```

But this returns this:

[image]

Comment: `alpha.concat(test[prop])`

Comment: What @Pointy said; also, you're making a new `second` array with each iteration of the `for` loop and then throwing it away, when I think you want to store the new array back in the `alpha` variable, yes?

Comment: ES2015, the entire code: `[].concat(...Object.keys(all).map(k => all[k]))`. Old syntax: `[].concat.apply([], Object.keys(all).map(k => all[k]))`

Comment: @apsillers hey, you're right - how do I do that? thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to get one array from the `all` object:

```
var test = Object.values(all).flat();
```

In older JavaScript versions, that do not support these functions, go for:

```
var test = Object.keys(all).reduce( (acc, a) => acc.concat(all[a]), [] );
```

To assign it to a `feed_0` property, is of course not the difficulty:

```
test = { feed_0: test };
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your `feed_N` arrays into one property using `Object.keys` and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = {
  feed_0: [0, 1, 2],
  feed_1: [3, 4, 5],
  feed_2: [6, 7, 8],
  feed_3: [9, 10, 11]
}

data = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(result, k) {
  [].push.apply(result.feed_0, data[k])
  return result
}, { feed_0: [] })

console.log(data)
```